# Postgresql: Passing result of a select query to jsonb_to_recordset is not working

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with the below format.

TableName: data

[image: data table]

I have the below query to extract the `data2` jsonb.

```
select comment->data2 from data where id=1
```

I have to fetch the resulting jsonb as recordset like

[image]

I figured that `jsonb_to_recordset` will help in yielding the result as expected but when I tried to run the below query

```
select * from json_to_recordset(select comment->data2 from data where id=1) as x(valueId text, valueType text);
```

but i get the below error

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: select * from json_to_recordset(select comment->data2...
```

Can someone guide on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the inner select in parentheses:

```
select * 
from json_to_recordset( (select comment->data2 from data where id=1) ) as x(valueId text, valueType text);
```

Comment: The error went away but the result is an empty table. Anything more needs to be done?

Comment: It is so confusing as the example provided in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html) works as expected.
`select * from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"a":1,"b":"foo"},{"a":"2","c":"bar"}]') as x(a int, b text);`

Comment: while the jsonb for my usecase (example in main question was sample this is more closer to real data) is not working even in it's simplest form.
`select * from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"fieldId":"1","fieldType":"selection","fieldValue":"6120"},{"fieldId":"2","fieldType":"selection"},{"fieldId":"3","fieldType":"text","fieldValue":"Sameple Text"},{"fieldId":"4","fieldType":"Text","fieldValue":"project code"}]') as x(fieldId text, fieldType text, fieldValue text);`

Comment: Okay I just figured out that it works as expected if the keys are completely lower case....not sure why that is the case and if it is a bug in postgresql. The below works.

```select * from json_to_recordset('[{"fieldid":"1","fieldtype":"selection","fieldvalue":"6120"},{"fieldid":"2","fieldtype":"selection"},{"fieldid":"3","fieldtype":"text","fieldvalue":"Sameple Text"},{"fieldid":"4","fieldtype":"Text","fieldvalue":"project code"}]') as x(fieldid text, fieldtype text, fieldvalue text);
```

Comment: Using "" worked to map the field names as is.
```x("fieldId" text, "fieldType" text, "fieldValue" text)```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it solved my initial query.